# Child a tag width 100% to the parent width in this case not working

Tags: css

I am trying an a tag take all 100% width of the parent but anything works. I tried with div tag and p tag and it works, do not know if i am missing something with a tags

html

```
<div >
  <a href="">dsa</a>
</div>
```

css

```
div {
   background: red;
   width: 500px;
   height: 20px;
}

div a {

  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kalugy/pen/XWEpmXY)

Comment: add an css for your  div  **display: flex** like
div {
   background: red;
   width: 500px;
   height: 20px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display: inline-block` for `a` tag.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
}

div a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="">dsa</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add css your div as

> **display:flex**

```css
div {
   background: red;
   width: 500px;
   height: 30px;
   display:flex;
}

div a {
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <a href="">dsa</a>
</div>
```